# Jenkins deployment

Tags: node.js, azure, jenkins, angular5

I am getting the below mentioned error when i am trying to build my app through Jenkins.

remote: npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
remote: npm ERR! sha512-d7r5njiOKUND9m1FbjCtIzYGUD7hl9sdyvbH3OsDqR3aW+XB7qmZPQ+uQWBNYh+h8Zm9G6e2eDJjx0evOTe9xQ== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-d7r5njiOKUND9m1FbjCtIzYGUD7hl9sdyvbH3OsDqR3aW+XB7qmZPQ+uQWBNYh+h8Zm9G6e2eDJjx0evOTe9xQ== but got sha512-gXvGMnj54hIhBsUUrFBgXzhCe84xaGpMACqvW4ViF4j0n2xXO+IwWPPkal17FUvVrzd82sXqFAWDGXdasEFGrw==. (1163 bytes)

How to solve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm having this problem as well (angular 7 npm 5.6).  When I manually run npm install on our CI server, everything is fine.  When Jenkins builds automatically on the the same server, I get the EINTEGRITY error.